# How to deploy web console by docker, docker run -d -p 80:80 -v <host_absolute_path>:/var/lib/mongodb --name, What is host absolute path?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, ignite

I'm trying to deploy Apache Ignite Web console on Linux(CentOS 7), but to run docker, i have to set host_absolute_path of MongoDB, How to handle it?

`<host_absolute_path>` is a path on your host machine where MongoDB will create database files. This folder should be created before docker run. Go to Docker->Preferences->File Sharing and create the directory there or use the other way that suits your more.
Can anybody explain step by step?

```sh
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v <host_absolute_path>:/var/lib/mongodb --name web-console-standalone apacheignite/web-console-standalone
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be any folder on your machine where you want the data to be kept?

Comment: It is the full path to the folder you want to share on your host computer. Not just a relative path, something like `/home/me/theproject/data/mongodb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<host_absolute_path>` is just a path on your local machine. MongoDB is embedded into the docker image. You need to specify a path where MongoDB will store data.
It's required because data need to survive restarts of the container. For example you can run:

`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 -v /home/user/mongodb:/var/lib/mongodb apacheignite/web-console-standalone:2.7.0`

It will run Web console 2.7.0 on 8080 port of the host machine and store data in `/home/user/mongodb`. This directory should be already present when you start the container.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:
something like below worked

```sh
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v D:\Softwares\IgniteProject\MangoDB:/var/lib/mongodb  --name web-console-standalone apacheignite/web-console-standalone
```